# Soundpool play several times android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, soundpool, android-sound

I have Problem playing soundpool .
I am new to education in Android and I hope you will help me.
I created class to load soundpool

```
 public class Suond {


    protected  static int suond1 ,suond2,suond3,suond4,suond5,suond6,suond7;
    protected  static  SoundPool sou;
    protected  static  AudioAttributes aa;


    @SuppressLint("NewApi") 
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

    protected static void oi(Context Con ){


         if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){

             aa = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
            .build();

 sou = new SoundPool.Builder().setMaxStreams(10)
.setAudioAttributes(aa).build();

                  suond1 = sou.load(Con,R.raw.Music1,1);
                  suond2 = sou.load(Con,R.raw.Music2,1);
                  suond3 = sou.load(Con,R.raw.Music3,1);
                  suond4 = sou.load(Con,R.raw.Music4,1);
                  suond5 = sou.load(Con,R.raw.Music5,1);
                  suond6 = sou.load(Con,R.raw.Music6,1);
                  suond7 = sou.load(Con,R.raw.Music7,1);
                           }

             else{ sou = new SoundPool(10,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,1);

                  suond1 = sou.load(Con,R.raw.Music1,1);
                  suond2 = sou.load(Con,R.raw.Music2,1);
                  suond3 = sou.load(Con,R.raw.Music3,1);
                  suond4 = sou.load(Con,R.raw.Music4,1);
                  suond5 = sou.load(Con,R.raw.Music5,1);
                  suond6 = sou.load(Con,R.raw.Music6,1);
                  suond7 = sou.load(Con,R.raw.Music7,1);

                 }  

                }               

    }
```

I also have 10 buttons representing levels in the game In each button textview Contains a value used with an animated listener for each text view At the end of the listener, use soundpool.

```
valueAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
      @Override
      public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {


        suond.sou.play(Suond.suond1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);

      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {


          Suond.sou.play(Suond.suond2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);






      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

      }
    });

 valueAnimator.setDuration(2000);
 valueAnimator.start();
 }
```

Each button has a listener connected to each other, where when the listener plays the first button, the animation starts with the second and third button to the tenth button respectively. Everything goes well but when the animation reaches the eighth button and sometimes the ninth or tenth the sound disappears until the activity leaves and returns two or three times to the sound activity back to play.
In my guess I think the sound stopped because of playing several times in a row but when I read about Soundpool it's dedicated to playing short sounds and can play more than  sound at the same time can play up to 16 sounds at the same time in my application sounds are not playing At the same time but respectively and that the sounds he used did not exceed 30 KB.
I don't know what is wrong.
Why the sound stops playing when you play it several times in a row.
I use Android 4.0
Thank you very much and hope to help me with any solutions.

Answer (score 1):

(1) You have typo's in your code so how did you get it to compile ?

```
Suond.sou.play(Suond.suond2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
suond.sou.play(Suond.suond1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
```

anyway it should be:

```
Suond.sou.play(Suond.suond2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
```

(2) MaxStreams is set to 10 so you can only have 10 concurrent streams (not 16):

```
sou = new SoundPool.Builder().setMaxStreams(10).setAudioAttributes(aa).build();
else{ sou = new SoundPool(10,AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,1);
```

(3) keep track of your active sounds (`Suond.sou.play` returns an integer):

```
int streamID = Suond.sou.play(Suond.suond2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);//streamID better as an integer array
```

(4) Remember to tidy-up after you leave the activity (If you're not going to use it after the activity finishes, then release in `onDestroy()`.):

```
//loop round your active sounds
sou .stop(streamID) ;stop ONE active sound
sou .release();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have created  streamID Each voice, as I said in the answer, but the problem still exists And when using sou .release();  Returning to activity the sound does not work I hope you will give me more clarification if you have a solution and thank you very much.

Comment: Suond.suond2 is a soundID not a streamID, different things. When you onPause() and onResume() your activity you need to stop and start things again. See this tutorial:-       https://www.101apps.co.za/articles/using-android-s-soundpool-class-a-tutorial.html

Comment: Yes, I read this educational program before and read it now more than once But I could not solve the problem, perhaps because the mother tongue was not English because of a problem in understanding some of the terms I needed more detail.

Comment: I use every listener in the valueAnimator this way.int streamID = Suond.sou.play(Suond.suond2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);And inside onPause() use Suond.sou.stop(streamID);
      Suond.sou.release();
      Suond.sou = null; And inside onResume() use Suondapp.sou.resume(streamID);
     Is this good Thank you

Comment: Your getting there, I know exactly the best way to do this, but there is no substitute for you trying things yourself, so you can learn.

Comment: I searched a lot and could not find anything to tell me where the problem was or to understand why this mistake was made I need to know what is wrong so that I can search the right ways I have tried many methods but the problem exists in all ways This made my mental stray I was hoping for some help Thank you